# Not receiving email sent using powershell command

Tags: powershell, scripting

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "smtp.com.au" -From "me@me.com" -To "you@you.com" -Subject "Testing" -Attachments "\\Test\archive.zip" -Body "attached"
```

I am using the above command to email a zip file but i don't see anything in the To (you@you.com) mailbox.

The command runs successfully without any errors.

Comment: Until someone provides an insight, you can try debugging the network request using Fiddler.

Comment: Any difference if you skip the zip-file?

Comment: @notjustme haven't tried without the zip file, thanks i will try this tomorrow when at work !!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your function call. You miss a lot of parameters. Take a look on my working gmail example:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "123456789" -AsPlainText -Force
$emailCredentials = New-Object pscredential ("from@gmail.com", $password)
try {
    Send-MailMessage -From "from@gmail.com" -To "to@to.com" -Subject "subject" -Body "body" -SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -Port 587 -Credential $emailCredentials -Encoding UTF8 -UseSsl -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    echo $error[0]
}
```

There is no `-Credential` parameter in your call, and I'm almost sure, that's the problem. Also your smtp server may have this protocol on different port, this is what `-Port` is for. And finally `-UseSsl`, if smtp server is encrypting mails, then without this switch, your emails will be not send. `-Encoding UTF8` is just for regional chars.

Check your `$error[0]`, it may tell you, where the problem is. Check what is happening on your `-From` email. On gmail you can see sometimes auto-repiles, with error description.

I'm sorry for not giving you simple solution, but I don't have enough informations, to find it.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but i am getting the following error message.Send-MailMessage : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:4 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage -From "b@n.com" -To "b@hot ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys i have an update:

My command mentioned above is working absolutely fine. IT  team has told me that we had issues with our SMTP the other day (When i had reported this issue) the emails eventually did come in (too late). I have tested the same this morning and it seems to be fine so a big thanks to all for your support.

I have got another question but i will post it separately.

Comment: I too have the same problem. Don't know what happened :( Unable to find the solution still :(